# Opening new connections increase the cpu usage of database generating poor response time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

We have an application running in 2 or 6 ec2 c5x.large AWS instances.
Our configuration is:
4 worker 5 threads

Usually we use two instances but in a specific time we are sending a push notifications to users what ends on mmany user entering at same time generating this situation.

We have 8 instances with 4 workers and 5 threads but number of database connections is around 40. But in 1 minute we pass from 50-60 connections to 120 connections. Generating a peak of database cpu usage and ending on a poor response time.

So we are trying to prevent this problem. We assume that as the database cpu is busy generating the new connections our queries are in waiting status generating a problem on response time.

Once connections are created and number request is not too big the response time goes back to his normal result.

Any advice on this?

We have tested to have more or less threads, more os less workers.
But nothing helps

Comment: Sounds like you need to increase the DB instance/resources, or maybe put in a read replica just to spread the load.